# Check all checkboxes on DataTables pages

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have the following DataTable, and I need to check / uncheck all checkboxes on all pages. How do I make this happen? Also, just the checkboxes and not the entire row.

[image]

I cannot use fnGetNodes, because it is deprecated.

```
 var table = new DataTable('#example', {
                responsive: true,
                "lengthMenu": [20, 40, 60, 80, 100],
                "pageLength": 10
            });
```

Full HTML :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js" integrity="sha256-eKhayi8LEQwp4NKxN+CfCh+3qOVUtJn3QNZ0TciWLP4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/2.0.2/js/dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/2.0.2/css/dataTables.dataTables.min.css">    
  </head>
<body>
    <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>

                <th><input type="checkbox" name='all' id="checkAll"> All</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="1"></td>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011-04-25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="2"></td>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011-07-25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="3" checked></td>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009-01-12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="4"></td>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012-03-29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="5"></td>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008-11-28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="6"></td>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012-12-02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="7"></td>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012-08-06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="8"></td>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010-10-14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="9"></td>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>2009-09-15</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="10"></td>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008-12-13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="11"></td>
                <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2008-12-19</td>
                <td>$90,560</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="12"></td>
                <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2013-03-03</td>
                <td>$342,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="13"></td>
                <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>2008-10-16</td>
                <td>$470,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="14"></td>
                <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2012-12-18</td>
                <td>$313,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="15"></td>
                <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>2010-03-17</td>
                <td>$385,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="16"></td>
                <td>Michael Silva</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2012-11-27</td>
                <td>$198,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="17"></td>
                <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2010-06-09</td>
                <td>$725,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="18"></td>
                <td>Gloria Little</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2009-04-10</td>
                <td>$237,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="19"></td>
                <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2012-10-13</td>
                <td>$132,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="20"></td>
                <td>Dai Rios</td>
                <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>2012-09-26</td>
                <td>$217,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="21"></td>
                <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                <td>Development Lead</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2011-09-03</td>
                <td>$345,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="22"></td>
                <td>Yuri Berry</td>
                <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>2009-06-25</td>
                <td>$675,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="23"></td>
                <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2011-12-12</td>
                <td>$106,450</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="24" checked></td>
                <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>Sydney</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2010-09-20</td>
                <td>$85,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="25"></td>
                <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009-10-09</td>
                <td>$1,200,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="26"></td>
                <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>2010-12-22</td>
                <td>$92,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="employeeID" class="select-employee" value="27"></td>
                <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2010-11-14</td>
                <td>$357,650</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br/>
   

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function(){
            
            var table = new DataTable('#example', {
                responsive: true,
                "lengthMenu": [20, 40, 60, 80, 100],
                "pageLength": 10
            }); 

                             
           // check / uncheck all somehow? 
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't believe you can check a checkbox that isn't on the page (since they don't currently exist). You'd have to show all the records on a single page or find another way to retrieve all the ids/values for all the records to use.  What will happen to the checked records?

Comment: There's an example of how to do that [here](https://live.datatables.net/mutavegi/6/edit).  If you look at the JS, it is iterating over every cell in the table (`table.cells(null, 0).every( function () {...}`, finding the checkbox in that cell and checking or unchecking it. You can probably limit the iteration to just the column that contains the checkbox.

Comment: Actually, looking at the `cells()` [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cells()), it takes a column index as a parameter. In that example, they are iterating over the cells in the first column (index 0), not all cells.

Answer (score 0):

This works. Source : https://live.datatables.net/mutavegi/6/edit

```
 var table = new DataTable('#example', {
                responsive: true,
                "lengthMenu": [20, 40, 60, 80, 100],
                "pageLength": 10
            }); 

            $('#checkAll').on('change', function(){
                var checked = $(this).prop('checked');
                table.cells(null, 0).every(function(){
                    var cell = this.node();
                    $(cell).find('input[type="checkbox"][name="employeeID"]').prop('checked', checked); 
                });
            });
```